# Unable to set the recorded values in the field while playing the recording

Tags: katalon-studio

Unable to set the recorded data to the field (which was recorded) while re-playing the test case.

I have used absolute XPath as a temporary solution but it is not the best practice as mentioned n Katalon site.

Each piece of data for the recorded field must be inserted after playing the test cases but not all data is inserted to the specified field.

Comment: I am using katalon studio @JimGrigoryan

Comment: Did you try writing the xpaths yourself?

Comment: i used Xpath by inspecting it in browser but i did not try writing it on my own@MateMrše . Have you got any solutions regarding this issue  ?

Comment: @DamodarBhandari Xpaths generated by recording tools tend to be pretty brittle. It is much better to write them yourself. Please share the HTML of the page in question and the recorded script and maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @DamodarBhandari : Please show your code and site under test if possible.